# $\mathcal{F}_\infty$-measurablity of a random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes, measurable-functions, filtrations

Let $X$ be a r.v. and $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ be i.i.d. integrable r.v.'s independent of $X$, with $E[Y_i]=0$.

Here, we consider $Z_i = X + Y_i$, and let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be filtration s.t. $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma (Z_1, \dots , Z_n)$ and $\mathcal{F}_\infty = \cup_n^\infty \mathcal{F}_n$.

Here, I think $X$ must be $\mathcal{F}_\infty$-measurable, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Your $\mathcal F_{\infty}$ is not a $\sigma-$ field.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks, you are right. It should be $\mathcal{F}_\infty = \sigma (\cup _n \mathcal{F})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X+Y_i) = X + \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$.  Each $S_n$ is $\mathcal F_\infty$ measurable, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = X$ a.s. by the strong law of large numbers.  Since $X$ is the a.s. limit of a sequence of $\mathcal F_{\infty}$-measurable random variables, $X$ is also $\mathcal F_{\infty}$-measurable.

Comment: Good arguemnt but there are two points to be noted. 1) OP shold define $\mathcal{F}_\infty $ as $\sigma ( \cup_n^\infty \mathcal{F}_n)$. 2) Your argument shows that $X$ is measurable w.r.t the completion of $\mathcal F_{\infty}$, not $\mathcal F_{\infty}$ itself.

Comment: @geetha290krm Why do we need completeness?

Comment: @geetha290krm I thought it was fairly obvious they meant $\sigma(\bigcup_n^\infty \mathcal F_n)$.  The fact that this requires completeness is a good point (because we only have an a.s. limit), and I'm not sure if $X$ is necessarily $\mathcal F_\infty$-measurable without completing it.